# Connecting a java program with an android application

Tags: java, android, connection

I'm rather clueless how you connect your android app to a java program.
I have coded a java application on my computer and i'd like to make an android application which calls e.g. a button press in the pc java application by the click of a button in the android app.I am slightly familiar with android studio, but not connecting devices like this.
How do i do this?

Comment: Please post any attempts you have done to solve your problem, and any issues that arose out of it. Please also check out how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: problem is i havent tried solving the problem as i have no clue what to look at or where to start. And google searches dont really help me sadly.
I'm mainly interested in knowing where i can find some information as for how to calling functions in pc program from android app

Comment: @AndersLassen Can you at least provide how much control you have over the Java PC and Android side. Also what timing requirements are you thinking of. For example don't bother with a button on the PC but a webservice which the Android app accesses.

Comment: Another website is better for that. StackOverflow primarily deals with specific questions, and something like [asking for a resource to learn how to do something is considered off-topic here.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Well i'm primarly interested in a piece of code to be called on the computer, when i press a button on my android device before 7 seconds have passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm rather clueless how you connect your android app to a java program

Though there are multiple ways of doing it but you can always connect any two Applications no matter what the platform is to each other using **Sockets**.
But For **Java** and **Android** First check out .

- Sockets programming in java [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html)
- Socket programming in android [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/)

Then you can execute specific tasks on both sides of your application depending on the data send by each application.

Happy coding :)